# Android/Java: Is there a way to know how often an external method has been called?

Tags: android, debugging

For instance, if I want to know how often bitmap.decodeResource is getting executed (either directly from my app or through any 3rd party libraries I'm including), is that possible?

Comment: @matheszabi lol, care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profiling

See [Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)